# Use huge Numpy array without storing it all in the memory

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, parser-generator

I have pickled a numpy array which contains cosine similarity matrix i have 8 GB Ram in my pc but whenever i want to use that pickled matrix i have to load it completely into the memory and it takes approx: 6 GB of Ram is there any way that i can handle this matrix so it only uses a very little amount of memory and loads and unloads time by time into the memory, like when i want to use the matrix i just simply use this by itterating over and performing my task without taking that huge array into my memory.

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

Comment: `np.load` also has a memmap mode.